# I need to replace all occurences of a string with the same text variable if exists php

Tags: php, str-replace

For example:

```
$str = 'This is stackoverflow and stackexchange.';
```

If we have defined variables ``` $stackoverflow = 'awesome';``$stackexchange = 'great'; ```

then `$str` becomes:

`'This is awesome and great.'`

Comment: What is the problem? Can you share your code? This sounds very simple task.

Comment: I have already shared the sample code. I have 10-15 such variables. And don't want to write str_replace for all

Comment: You post only have variable declaration and you have not specified what you have tried? and you don't want to use str_replace function.

Comment: This kind of information helps others to understand the question in better way.

Comment: edited the code. Is that fine?

Comment: That's seems fine now. Thanks. Do you want to execute any other function if variable exists? If NOT then you can use the str_replace as per the answer posted by @arunrc . If variable doesn't exists then it should be fine as it should not affect the program

Answer (score 0):

```
str_ireplace(array('stackoverflow','stackexchange'),array('awesome','great'),$your_string);
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I dont want to hard-code variable names. I want PHP to check if variable exists and then replace it in the string

Comment: you want to just replace the strings isn't it? or anything more?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You can put all the names in array.

```
<?php
  $old_values = array('stackoverflow','stackexchange');
  $new_values = array('awesome','great');
  $str = 'This is stackoverflow and stackexchange.';
  $str = str_replace($old_values,$new_values,$str);
?>
```